# How do you break out of recursion with no base case

Tags: java, recursion, break, maze

So im working on this program that will recursively solve a maze that i get from a txt file.  I put the maze into a 2d array.  Here is an example of the most simple maze.

```
+-+-+-+
|S|   |
+ + + +
|   |E|
+-+-+-+
```

i know im probably not going about solving the maze in the best way but i think my way works i just need to know how to break out of my recursion loop.  What im doing is checking if there is a boarder in the next place and if there is a '*' two places later if not then i move there and put down a marker.  This got me to the end of the maze but it breaks after.  I need a way to break out of the loop.  I just started learning about recursion so i think this is the problem but im not exactly sure.

The wrong choice method will return me to the last place where there is a cell with an open boarder and a no '*' with in two places.

```
public static void solveMaze(int COL, int ROW){
   //find first open cell and choose it

         if(drawArray[COL][ROW+1] == ' ' && drawArray[COL][ROW+2] != '*'){
            //if(drawArray[COL][ROW+2] == 'E')

            drawArray[COL][ROW+2] = '*';
            ROW+= 2;
            solveMaze(COL,ROW);
         }  
         else if(drawArray[COL+1][ROW] == ' ' && drawArray[COL+2][ROW] != '*'){
            drawArray[COL+2][ROW] = '*';
            COL+= 2;
            solveMaze(COL,ROW);
         }
         else if(drawArray[COL][ROW-1] == ' ' && drawArray[COL][ROW-2] != '*'){
            drawArray[COL][ROW-2] = '*';
            ROW-= 2;
            solveMaze(COL,ROW);        
         }
         else if(drawArray[COL-1][ROW] == ' ' && drawArray[COL-2][ROW] != '*'){
            drawArray[COL-2][ROW] = '*';
            COL+= 2;
            solveMaze(COL,ROW);
         }
         else 
            wrongChoice(COL,ROW); 


   }
```

Comment: If you're going to recursion, you'll need a base case.  The base case here would be when you're at the end point.  How can you detect that case, and what should you do when it happens?

Comment: I believe finding out the base case is the first thing to do before writing out a recursive function.

Comment: There is no "recursion loop". There is no loop. I know this probably sounds nitpicky and pedantic to you, but I've found that using correct terminology is an important step for correctly organizing your thoughts regarding technical material, and misusing terminology is often an indicator of conceptual misunderstandings.

Comment: If you're trying to get from S to E, then the base case is "I'm already at E".

Answer (score 0):

One can provide a **partial result** (initially empty) as parameter. And one can return a result.
Another parameter for recursion often is the set of **possible candidates**.

For instance something like:

```
public static void solveMaze(int COL, int ROW, Path pathTaken) {
    Path pathTaken = new Path();
    if (solveMazeRecursively(START_COL, START_ROW, pathTaken)) {
        ...
    }
}

private static boolean solveMazeRecursively(int COL, int ROW, Path pathTaken) {
    if (drawArray[COL][ROW+1] == 'E') {
        System.out.println(pathTaken);
        return true;
    }
    // The real work...
    if (drawArray[COL][ROW+1] == ' ' && drawArray[COL][ROW+2] != '*'){
        drawArray[COL][ROW+2] = '*';
        ROW += 2;
        takenPath.add(COL, ROW+2);
        if (solveMazeRecursively(COL,ROW, takenPath)) {
            return true;
        }
        takenPath.remove(COL, ROW+2);
     }
```

Recursion implies being lazy checking first whether nothing has to be done (solution present, or impossible to continue), and otherwise delegating to new function instances.